# MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTimeZoneName on channel dexterx.dev/trail))

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

i am using flutter local notification for scheduling, when i use an MethodChannel instance i get an exception.

**the main function:**

```
const MethodChannel platform = MethodChannel('dexterx.dev/apptrail');

    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      await _configureLocalTimeZone();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

**_configureLocalTimeZone function is:**

```
Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  final String timeZoneName = await platform.invokeMethod('getTimeZoneName');
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
}
```

**the Exception is:**

```
 Exception has occurred.
    MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTimeZoneName on channel dexterx.dev/trail))
```

Comment: Did you write an implementation for the method channel on the native side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example code of `flutter_local_notifications` has native implement part
You can reference
https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/ac730a0298edd8335cde07a09a396c46cc8c9292/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/dexterous/flutter_local_notifications_example/MainActivity.kt#L23

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "dexterx.dev/flutter_local_notifications_example").setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if ("drawableToUri" == call.method) {
                val resourceId = this@MainActivity.resources.getIdentifier(call.arguments as String, "drawable", this@MainActivity.packageName)
                result.success(resourceToUriString(this@MainActivity.applicationContext, resourceId))
            }
            if ("getAlarmUri" == call.method) {
                result.success(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM).toString())
            }
            if ("getTimeZoneName" == call.method) {
                result.success(TimeZone.getDefault().id)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the method on the native side. So when you invoke that method from Flutter's side, it isn't found in the native code upon searching, hence exception is raised.